# You have to be inside angular -cli project to run this command and port 4200 is already in use

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

With ng serve error "you have to be inside angular cli project"
npm start port 4200 already in use.
I checked ng -v locally and globally and angular versions are same.
Error messages

> npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 npm ERR! argv
>   "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" npm ERR! node v6.17.1 npm ERR!
>   npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! frontend@0.1.2 start:
>   `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.2 start script
>   'ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json'. npm ERR!
>   Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the frontend
>   package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that
>   this fails on your system: npm ERR!     ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
>   --proxy-config proxy.conf.json npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs frontend
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm
>   ERR!     npm owner ls frontend npm ERR! There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/frontend/npm-debug.log

Comment: Are you sure you're in an Angular project root, and another is not already running on port 4200? That's what the error is saying.

Comment: @Phix yes i hope so i am running a existing angular application for the first time, i have attached the screenshot for the structure

Comment: So assuming you ran `ng new project-name`, did you change into that directory before running serve? This issue has been widely run into and solved elsewhere. Without steps to reproduce it's hard to say.

Comment: try npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: @phix,i have zip file of project, unzip it, i am now inside the project and I did npm install and than ng serve

Comment: Running ng serve would use the globally installed CLI, does running npm start make a difference?

Comment: @phix--with npm start> paperarchive-frontend@0.1.2 start /home/bc903/Paper Archive/dbg-paper-archive-master/paper-archive-frontend
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://0.0.0.0:4200. **
Hash: b8a000d32e50ae915dc8
Time: 28999ms
chunk    {0} 0.chunk.js, 0.chunk.js.map 30.1 kB {1} {2} {3} {4} [rendered]
chunk    {1} 1.chunk.js, 1.chunk.js.map 34.5 kB {0} {2} {3} {4} [rendered]
chunk    {2} 2.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js.map 36.6 kB {0} {1} {3} {4} [rendered]

Comment: chunk    {4} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 710 kB {7} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 295 kB {8} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {6} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 1.2 MB {8} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {7} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 5.99 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {8} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:4200| xargs kill -9

npm start
```